# Drawing bezier curve from a parabola

Tags: conic-sections, bezier-curve

I'm not a math guy, sorry. I read posts on the subject but couldn't find the answer to my problem (or didn't understood the answers). I'd like to get a simple answer.

I know a *generic parabola formula*

$$(Pa.x+Pb.y)^2+Pc.x+Pd.y+Pe=0$$

it *focus*, $(Fx,Fy)$

and the cartesian equation of it's *directrix*

$$Da.x+Db.y+Dc=0$$

What would be the easiest way to draw a portion of it using a quadratic bezier curve (say maybe from it summit up to $2p$ or like) ?

Comment: Welcome the MathematicsStackExchange! You can improve your experience by using MathJax for equations. A quick review is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: How are you “drawing” the curve? What do you consider easy?

Comment: I want to draw the curve using SVG path Q/q command. Want I mean by "easy" is with the less computation possible.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve#Second_order_curve_is_a_parabolic_segment

Comment: Do you know how to compute the position and first derivative at any point on the parabola from your "generic parabola formula"?

Answer (score 0):

- Choose at will start point $P_0$ and end point $P_2$ on your parabola.
- Find the equations of tangent lines at $P_0$ and $P_2$.
- Find the intersection point $P_1$ of the two tangents.
- The quadratic Bézier $B(t)=(1-t)^2P_0+2t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2$ is what you want.

Comment: Souds logical. My problem is to choose p0 and p2.

Comment: I interpret "from its summit" as meaning that $P_0$ is the vertex of the parabola. And that's easy because the vertex is the midpoint between the focus and the projection of the focus on the directrix.The meaning of "up to $2p$ or like" is otherwise rather obscure, to me at least.

Comment: Yep F is the focus and p is the parabola parameter, which is the length of the orthogonal projection of F on the directrix.

Comment: Do you then want to choose $P_2$ such that its distance from the directrix is $2p$? If so,  $P_2$ is the intersection between the parabola and one of the two lines with equation $D_a x+D_b y+D_c\pm 2p\sqrt{D_a^2+D_b^2}=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds logical.